# Using 2FA with Exchange Online Plan 1

Tags: office365, exchange, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I am looking to help someone purchase Exchange Online Plan 1 ([EOP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/exchange/exchange-online?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)) and I want to have them use Two Factor Authentication (2FA). I am getting mixed messages from Microsoft and other resources when I ask if I can enable 2FA with EOP1.

It is my understanding (and this may be where the flaw is) that EOP1 uses Azure AD Free to authenticate. While I don't see it documented that EOP1 supports 2FA it does look like Azure AD Free does ([Features and licenses for Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing)). Can someone help confirm for me whether I can get 2FA with EOP1 without an additional cost?

A follow-up question would be whether the 2FA can include SMS (text to cell) without additional cost or if it is limited to an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all Microsoft 365 plans, Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication can be enabled on a per-user basis, or enabled or disabled for all users using security defaults. And what @g_mac mentioned in [***this thread***](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/identity-authentication/is-mfa-included-in-office-365-exchange-online-plan-1/m-p/1427720/highlight/true#M1153) seems could also prove that.

Here is some other information I found, for your reference:

[Available versions of Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing#available-versions-of-azure-ad-multi-factor-authentication)

[Multi factor authentication in Office 365 - SMS charges](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_other-mso_o365b/multi-factor-authentication-in-office-365-sms/e8e3f779-0843-4f7d-8db9-37772c68870c)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.

Comment: [This is correct, MFA is available for every plan.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults#availability)

Conditional access is not available to everyone.

[This is how to enable these settings.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults#enabling-security-defaults)